# Give an example of a metric space not homeomorphic to any subspace of Euclidean space $\Bbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

The question is exactly like in the title.

Comment: I've seen other sites where the "question" is like what you wrote, along the lines of "The title says it all". However, on this site, if the title of your question actually does say all that your question is going to say, then on this site your question is likely to be closed. You should provide some context, say something about what you've tried, or where you got stuck, and so on. Take a look at [these suggestions on how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: I accept the rules and I don't mind the question being closed by admin, but I cannot see how I could ask for help with finding an example otherwise. Anyone knows that when studying topology for better understanding a bunch  of examples is needed and I think that someone who knows the topic better / studied it for longer might have wider range of them to choose from

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are asking for a metric space $(\Bbb{R}^n, d)$ which is not homeomorphic to $(\Bbb{R}^n, d_2)$ where $d_2$ is the standard Euclidean metric. In this case, let $d$ be the discrete metric. Then $(\Bbb{R}^n, d)$ is not homeomorphic to $(\Bbb{R}^n, d_2)$. This is because we can find non-open sets in $(\Bbb{R}^n, d_2)$ but every set is open in $(\Bbb{R}^n, d)$, hence there are no non-open sets, so the two cannot be homeomorphic. The same discussion but for $\Bbb{R}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/918223/252641).

Comment: The question is asking for a metric space which is not homeomorphic to any ***subspace*** of a Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n.$ I'm afraid your argument is a little too simple.

Comment: So if we take a subspace $A \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$, and consider the metrics $d$ and $d_2$ restricted to $A$, why does the same argument not hold? Presumably $(A, d)$ and $(A, d_2)$ will not be homeomorphic. I suspect also that there isn't a subspace $B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^n$ such that $(A, d) \cong (B, d_2)$ but I'm not sure how to show this.